# Bound on number of linearly independent eigenvectors of adjoint of composition operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ds.dynamical-systems, operator-theory

Fix $N>1$.  Let $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ be such that the composition operator via
$$
\begin{aligned}
C_f:C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})  &\rightarrow C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})
\\
g & \mapsto g \circ f,
\end{aligned}
$$
is a bounded operator.  Here the topology on $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ is the [Whitney topology](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/C-infinity+topology).

Let $C^f$ denote the adjoint operator $C_f$.  Is there a criterion on $f$ to verify when $C^f$ has at most $N$ linearly independent eigenvectors?

Comment: What topology do you use on $C(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ (so that it makes sense to talk about a *bounded operator* and about the *adjoint operator*)?

Comment: @JochenGlueck I meant $C^{\infty}$; also, the topology is Whitney's one.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: My pleasure :)  Thanks for pointing it out.